# Object with another's object's property as a key

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this:
var myObj = {action1:0, action2:1, action3:2};

Test function gets values from this list as parameters and to simplify unit-testing I want to get human readable labels inside of the function

```
function myFunc(someaction, anotheraction, blablabla)
{
    console.log("Action: " + arguments[0] + " then action: " + arguments[1]);
    //some code here
}
```

So inside of the function I can see only values like 0 1 2

Trying to workaround I tried to create new object like this

```
var dictObj = {myObj.action1:"action1", myObj.action2:"action2", myObj.action3:"action3"}
```

and then resolve values to names inside of the function:

```
console.log("Action: " + dictObj[arguments[0]] + " then action: " + dictObj[arguments[1]]);
```

But it didn't work because of

```
'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .'
```

How I can rework this code to get readable description?

Comment: do it like : `var dictObj = {}; dictObj[myObj.action1] = "action1"; dictObj[myObj.action2] = "action2"; dictObj[myObj.action3] = "action3";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ES5 and earlier, you have to create that object with a series of statements:

```
var dictObj = {};
dictObj[myObj.action1] = "action1";
dictObj[myObj.action2] = "action2";
dictObj[myObj.action3] = "action3";
```

As of ES2015 (aka "ES6"), you can do it with computed property names in the object initializer instead:

```
let dictObj = {
    [myObj.action1]: "action1",
    [myObj.action2]: "action2",
    [myObj.action3]: "action3"
};
```

You can use any expression within the `[]` to create the property name; in this case it's just a simple property lookup.

In both cases, note that there's no *live* relationship; if you change `myObj.action1` to 42 *later*, after doing the above, it doesn't have any effect on the property name in `dictObj`.

Comment: I don't know about the second method :) learned new things today

Comment: Hmm...I was sure I tried this way also but failed, also I tried to use quotes to escape dot (dictObj['myObj.action1'] = "action1";).
Anyway your suggestion worked